# ExpoAV Video, video I get from Django server is not loading

Tags: django, react-native, video, expo, expo-av

I am working on an Expo app and I use the  component from expo-av. When I source the video from my assets, it works. But when I try to display a video which is stored on my Django server, it is not loading.

here is my code

```
                 <Video
                  style={{width: window.width * .93, height: window.width * .93 * 1.05,}} 
                    source={{uri: server + "media/" + media.uri}}  
                    shouldPlay
                    usePoster
                    />
```

When I do the url on http request, I get the video I want. But it is not working on the expo app. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that `server + "media/" + media.uri` resolve in a relative URI - `path/to/file.mp4` which not intended URI.

An absolute URI - `https://your-domain.com/path/to/video.mp4` is required to stream video from server.

Comment: I checked and the {server + "media/" + media.uri} is ```http://your-domain.com/path/to/video.mp4``` and when I look it up it gives me the right video

Comment: `HTTPS` is required for iOS. Don't server video from insecure HTTP server

Comment: What do I do if I store the video on a Django server that has an HTTP domain?

Comment: Enable SSL Certificate on that domain or use Cloud providers to host static assets (videos,images,...)

Comment: thank you!! I ended up using a cloud provider.

Comment: Cool. Glad you figure out. Happy Hacking!